# How do I prove that this conditional expectation equates to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am tasked with answering **the following question:**

[image]

**Idea:**

I understand what the sets in $\mathscr{G}$ look like (i.e. potentially a series of sets on one side of $\frac{1}{2}$ and the corresponding symmetrical representation on the right). Also, my understanding is that $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathscr{G}]$ describes what can be deduced about the value of $X$ given this symmetry about $\frac{1}{2}$.

Would I be correct to somehow show that: $$\int_G X(\omega) \ d\mathbb{P} = \int_G \frac{1}{2} \ d\mathbb{P} ,\ \ \forall G \in \mathscr{G}$$ Because then it would surely follow that $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathscr{G}] = \frac{1}{2}$, right? The issue is I'm not sure if this approach is correct or how to actually do that if it is.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide!

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

For $B=A\cup(1-A) \in \mathcal G$, then by 
\begin{align}\mathbb E[X\mathbf1_{B}]&=\int_{B}X(ω)d\mathbb P=\int_{A}X(ω)d\mathbb P+\int_{1-A}X(ω)d\mathbb P=\int_{A}ω\;d\mathbb P+\int_{1-A}ω\;d\mathbb P\\[0.3cm]&=\int_{A}ω\;d\mathbb P+\int_{A}1-ω\;d\mathbb P=\int_{A}d\mathbb P=\mathbb P(A)=\frac12\mathbb P(B)\end{align} Since $ξ=\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ is by definition $\mathcal G-$ measurable and such that $$\mathbb E[X\mathbf 1_B]=\mathbb E[ξ\mathbf 1_B]$$ for all $B\in \mathcal G$, you get by the above that $$\frac12\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb E[ξ\mathbf 1_B]=ξ\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_B]=ξ\mathbb P(B)$$

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! It has helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you are right to show this equality, because (as per the definition of conditional expectation), you are supposed to show
$\mathbb E[XZ] = \mathbb E[\frac 1 2 Z]$ for all $\mathcal G$-measurable functions $Z$. Your equality of integrals is a special case where $Z = \Bbb 1_G$ where $G\in \mathcal G$. To extend to general $Z$ you can apply the functional monotone class theorem : http://math.ucsd.edu/~pfitz/downloads/courses/spring05/math280c/mct.pdf .

Now to prove your equality, try to do it yourself using the definition of $G$. It is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. I'm probably being a bit thick but if you take a set $G$ that is potentially some countable union of intervals, $(a_i, b_i)$, between $0$ and $1$, and then integrate $X(\omega) = \omega$ you get an exponent of order $2$, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}[ (b_1^2 - a_1^2) + (b_2^2 - a_2^2) + ...]$. But that seems undesirable - I presume I want that summation to equate to $\mathbb{P}(G)$, right?

Comment: The idea is that the symmetry of $G$ gives you very welcome compensations in this sum. But it is easier to write it for general $G$. $\int_G xdx = \int_A xdx + \int_{(1-A)}xdx$. Now we change variables $x=1-y$ in the second equation and get $\int_A xdx + \int_A(1-y)dy = \int_A dy$. Now the same change of variables allows you to compute $\mathbb P(G) = 2 \int_A dy$, combining everything gives $\int_G xdx = \frac 1 2 \mathbb P(G)$.

Comment: Oh! I see it. Haha, that's curiously obvious yet I couldn't see it clearly. Thanks so much!